# Java 8 time converter from 12 to 24 format

Tags: java, datetime-format

I trying a simple exercise to converter time from 12 to 24, below my code:

```
 String result = LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa")).toString();
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

The problem is when the seconds are 0 the method truncate the seconds,
for example with time 12:00:00AM the result is 00:00, I want it to be 00:00:00.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Formatting local time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701422/formatting-local-time-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the format:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME.format(LocalTime.of(0, 0))
// returns "00:00:00"
```

You can also use your own pattern. The following produces the same output:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(LocalTime.of(0, 0))
```

Comment: So, I have to split the time string, and in case it is AM or PM?

Comment: This format uses 24H, so AM/PM wasn't included. What do you mean by "split"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Faber `LocatTime.of(0,0)` was just an example. I believe in your case you have to call `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME.format(LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa")))` to get the desired output.